# Angular - How to assign the value "true" or "false" to the form controller in the validator?

Tags: angular

I have an HTML form and in this form there is a button that becomes active or inactive, depending on whether validation has been passed or not - this button listens to the “testForm.valid” parameter.

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (submit)="submit()">

  <input formControlName="email" type="email">

  <input formControlName="pass"  type="text">

  <button [disabled]="testForm.valid" type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

The same TypeScript class has a method called "submit()". This method is called every time I click the submit button. This method also does "httpRequest" every time.

```
    export class MyTestComponent {


      constructor(private httpRequest: HttpRequestService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      }



        this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({

            email: ['', {
              validators: [
                Validators.required]
            }],
            pass: ['', {
              validators: [
                Validators.required]
            }]

          }, {validators: this.testMail('email', 'pass')}
        )


      }


      public testMail(email: any, pass: any): ValidatorFn {

        return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

          // ....

          return null;

        }



      submit() {


        this.httpRequest.testRest().subscribe({
          next: () => {

            //...

          },
          error: (err) => {


          }
        });
      }

    }
```

If "httpRequest" returned an error, then I need to make sure that in the HTML form, the button is not active. That is, it is necessary that “testForm.valid” has the corresponding boolean value.

I want to ask you, dear users, how to make “testForm.valid” have the corresponding boolean value so that the button is not active. How to assign the desired value there? And this should come from the submit() method.

Thanks a lot to everyone who helps with the answer. I wish you a good day and good mood.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, your form isn’t necessarily invalid if the server returns an error. Probably easiest to introduce an error variable and set the button to inactive when either form.invalid or error. Btw, does it makes sense to disable a button an error? What is the user left to do when that happens?

Comment: @MikeOne I made a primitively simple example code. In reality, the code there is very complex. But that's the essence.

Comment: I wanted to make a separate variable, but it's insanely expensive.

Comment: And answering your question, I also thought about whether it’s worth disabling the button if the server returns an error. In fact, you don’t have to turn it off, but for beauty’s sake, I’d like to turn it off.